# How to type known dynamic keys?

Tags: typescript

Why the `TransformMap` type has problems with this line `[adEnabled ? 'userPrincipalName' : 'krbPrincipalName']: { key: 'loginName' }`? For some reason it can't be inferred the key will be either `userPrincipalName` or `krbPrincipalName`.

```
const adEnabled = parseInt(process.env.AD_ENABLED as string, 10);

type TransformMapValues = {
    key: string;
    transform?: (group: string) => string;
};

interface LdapUserMap {
    givenName: TransformMapValues;
    sn: TransformMapValues;
    mail: TransformMapValues;
    memberOf: TransformMapValues;
}

interface OpenLdapUserMap extends LdapUserMap {
    krbPrincipalName: TransformMapValues;
}

interface ADUserMap extends LdapUserMap {
    userPrincipalName: TransformMapValues;
}

type TransformMap = OpenLdapUserMap | ADUserMap;

const transformMap: TransformMap = {
    memberOf: {
        key: 'groups',
        transform: (group: string) => group.split(',')[0].split('=')[1],
    },
    mail: { key: 'email' },
    givenName: { key: 'firstName' },
    sn: { key: 'lastName' },
    [adEnabled ? 'userPrincipalName' : 'krbPrincipalName']: { key: 'loginName' },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript will only infer named keys from computed keys that are string literal types. Even if the computed keyis a union of string literal types it will fallback to inferring a string index instead of a named key:

```
const ky = Math.random() ? "k" : "y" // ky: "k" | "y"
const ky = Math.random() ? "k" : "y"

// let x: string = { [x: string]: string; }
let x = { [ky]: "" }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gTxgXhgWQIZQBYDoBOGYAJiALYAUAlDAPwwBEcDMAXIwgwFBcA2AprAAeKGAG8uMGAG1EAXXYNuAXyA)

If you use a object spread instead you will get the desired effect:

```
const transformMap: TransformMap = {
  memberOf: {
    key: 'groups',
    transform: (group: string) => group.split(',')[0].split('=')[1],
  },
  mail: { key: 'email' },
  givenName: { key: 'firstName' },
  sn: { key: 'lastName' },
  ...(adEnabled ? { 'userPrincipalName': { key: 'loginName' } } : { 'krbPrincipalName': { key: 'loginName' }] }),
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgEwKJjgIwDYFMEwLwwAOcAThFgJJhQAUhJIwWEEAdFmAG6sCCAIgH0kAOR4AhADJI+8CDGgkAlmADmAGhgBGAAwBKANwAoQ1ACehLDAAqJOJABmIEgFsAsnEIA1OBgCuzfBgAb0MYGABrLFMALnkoJVUjMPi7CEcXAH5YmhUGX0JYhWUVXXwAPjiElSMAXyNDZSgsEns4JhgJBA8AVXISd0Jg0JgVRU4OYThnLFibVPS3D28-ZiT5MFnbBydFrx9-CDXnOEUMTfmdgeWDo6xnNGaAeXtz7Zcr-dXDGuNG5tb2o8LGBOj0+gMYFgAB5NMAIOSgwi9ZoQkJhcIkNAABQSwEUxAwk2mrzSlyWn0O31+1H+bUs-GR-Q8kJhHHhHS6SPBzLRMF8fRxyjxBKJM2sW1J73JK0pPxM5ksczeu0CQI4iMZEIAPjAGdzCPVQJBYCllQMSQsIQRedN7k8XkMwuiorEAOS5ED5CCutTDZIShbZD35QrxYqlPAVYOEVgQQgYRS0H2u3QAbW0AF1Y-HEzRXXgU6nNBnfWEaqWYMdTrEghEXTBXXcThhXTBy8NRuMwKKa3WYg37IoyFBRa322EIBtgn23Rg4NBR22K6wVzRECh0NhcBlp67+c1BWBhT5R73Iv3XRgQKNu1MsGO2zBe66MdjcfiT3fXWf65fr8pFxqDM210X06iAA)